# C# Populated Array Property appearing as 'null' in Console app caller

Tags: c#

I am not a C# developer and just trying to piggy-back off C#'s ADO SQL functionality by writing a DLL for MATLAB to use (via its dotnet interface) to query a database. MATLAB only supports access to certain NET types so I must convert my `DataTable` columns to arrays of `strings`, `floats` etc.

I am writing a `RunReader` class under a `CDSOption` namespace with a class constructor which sets properties (to be used in creating the query), and a `Read` method which then concats a query (using these properties), uses a `SqlDataAdaptor` to fill a `DataTable` and assigns `DataTable` columns to arrays (such as `TickerArray`, that the DLL will expose to MATLAB).

However, I am finding that while the code seems to successfully query and populate the `TickerArray`, when I then try to access it from a console application `TickerArray` is simply `null` (see screenshot links).

Help from C# developers much appreciate.

---

**`RunReader.TickerArray` - `NullReferenceException` in console app**

[image: RunReader.TickerArray - NullReferenceException in console app]

---

**`TickerArray` is populated within `RunReader.Read`**

[image: TickerArray is populated within RunReader.Read]

---

**Console application for testing**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CDSOption;

namespace CDSOptionConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunReader runreader = new RunReader("ITXEB", "JPM", 5, 23, "2015-04-28", "2015-05-01");

            Console.WriteLine("RunReader Object Instantiated ... Reading\n\n");

            runreader.Read(); // query the db and populate Array properties

            Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows:\t" + runreader.Dataset.Rows.Count.ToString() + "\n\n");

            Console.WriteLine(runreader.TickerArray[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

**The `RunReader` class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CDSOption
{
    public class RunReader
    {
        public string Ticker;
        public string Broker;
        public int Tenor;
        public int Series;
        public string StartDate;
        public string EndDate;
        public int NumberOfRows;

        public DataTable Dataset;
        public String[] TickerArray;

        public RunReader(string ticker, string broker, int tenor, int series, string startdate, string enddate)
        {
            Ticker = ticker;
            Broker = broker;
            Tenor = tenor;
            Series = series;
            StartDate = startdate;
            EndDate = enddate;   
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=RB201067LT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CDSOptions;Integrated Security=true;";
            //conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            string queryfields = "r.run_id,r.ValueDate,r.Ticker,r.Series,r.Tenor, r.ExpiryDate,d.[Contract],d.Strike,d.Bid,d.Ask,d.ImpVol,d.Delta,r.RefSpread,r.FwdSpread,r.FwdDV01,d.Delta,d.Gamma,d.Theta,d.Vega";
            string queryjoin = "FROM [CDSOptions].[dbo].[CDSOption_RunData] d JOIN [CDSOptions].[dbo].[CDSOption_Run] r ON d.run_id=r.run_id";
            string querywhere = "WHERE r.Ticker = '" + Ticker + "' AND r.Tenor = '" + Tenor.ToString() + "' AND r.Broker = '" + Broker + "' AND r.ValueDate>='" + StartDate + "' AND r.ValueDate <= '" + EndDate + "'";


            command.CommandText = "SELECT " + queryfields + " " + queryjoin + " " + querywhere;

            //DataTable dataset = new DataTable();
            Dataset = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(Dataset);


            string[] TickerArray = new string[Dataset.Rows.Count];

            for (int row = 0; row < Dataset.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                TickerArray[row] = Dataset.Rows[row]["Ticker"].ToString();
            }


        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fill a **local** variable `TickerArray` in `RunReader.Read`.

Change `string[] TickerArray = new string[Dataset.Rows.Count];`
 to just 
`TickerArray = new string[Dataset.Rows.Count];`

Comment: indeed - who says there's no such thing as a stupid question! thank you.

Comment: np - the format of the question was OK and you showed that you tried something which is essentially what SO users want to see in order to help. If the answer solved your issue then please accept the answer as such (with the green checkmark).